# Output to excel.csv gives weird æøå

Tags: php, excel, slim-3

I just can't seem to make `ÆØÅ` give me right chars.

If I open Excel and then import from data and choice UTF-8 it will show correctly. but I can't ask my users to open excel and do this, so how do I make Excel open the file correctly the first time?

```
//Give our CSV file a name.
        $csvFileName = 'example.csv';

        //Open file pointer.        
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        //Loop through the associative array.
        foreach($sortedData as $row){
            //Write the row to the CSV file.                        
            fputcsv($fp, $row,";");
        }

        //Finally, close the file pointer.
        fclose($fp);

        $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="file.csv"');

        $stream = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');      

        return $response->withBody(new \Slim\Http\Stream($stream));
```

Comment: Perhaps if you used a different charset?  Perhaps if you used Western European?  Unless you have other characters that require the use of utf-8.

Comment: You tryed adding a BOM for those characters to your file?

Comment: I'm only using æøåÆØÅ as special chars tried adding a BOM but it added it to the actual csv file ? :/